# Getting vector obtained in the last layer of CNN before softmax layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, nlp

I am trying to implement a system by encoding inputs using CNN. After CNN, I need to get a vector and use it in another deep learning method.

```
  def get_input_representation(self):
    # get word vectors from embedding
    inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, self.input_placeholder)


    sequence_length = inputs.shape[1] # 56
    vocabulary_size = 160 # 18765
    embedding_dim = 256
    filter_sizes = [3,4,5]
    num_filters = 3
    drop = 0.5

    epochs = 10
    batch_size = 30

    # this returns a tensor
    print("Creating Model...")
    inputs = Input(shape=(sequence_length,), dtype='int32')
    embedding = Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=sequence_length)(inputs)
    reshape = Reshape((sequence_length,embedding_dim,1))(embedding)

    conv_0 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[0], embedding_dim), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(reshape)
    conv_1 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[1], embedding_dim), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(reshape)
    conv_2 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[2], embedding_dim), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(reshape)

    maxpool_0 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(sequence_length - filter_sizes[0] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(conv_0)
    maxpool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(sequence_length - filter_sizes[1] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(conv_1)
    maxpool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(sequence_length - filter_sizes[2] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(conv_2)

    concatenated_tensor = Concatenate(axis=1)([maxpool_0, maxpool_1, maxpool_2])
    flatten = Flatten()(concatenated_tensor)
    dropout = Dropout(drop)(flatten)
    output = Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')(dropout)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    adam = Adam(lr=1e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    adam = Adam(lr=1e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print("Traning Model...")
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint], validation_data=(X_test, y_test))  # starts training


    return ??
```

The above code, trains the model using `X_train` and `Y_train` and then tests it. However in my system I do not have `Y_train` or `Y_test`, I only need the vector in the last hidden layer before softmax layer. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can define a backend function to get the output of arbitrary layer(s):

```
from keras import backend as K

func = K.function([model.input], [model.layers[index_of_layer].output])
```

You can find the index of your desired layer using `model.summary()` where the layers are listed starting from index zero. If you need the layer before the last layer you can use `-2` as the index (i.e. `.layers` attribute is actually a list so you can index it like a list in python). Then you can use the function you have defined by passing a **list** of input array(s):

```
outputs = func(inputs)
```

Alternatively, you can also define a model for this purpose. This has been covered in [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) more thoroughly so I advise you to read that.