# How to store the flatten result of a CNN?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the following convolutional neural network to apply to images:

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape = (128, 128, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
```

After applying the convolutional and maxpooling layers, I flatten the results and want to store only that result (later I want to work with this result using unsupervised methods). How do I do that? The only examples I have continue the proccess to fit the model and I never store the flatten layers.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further? What do you mean by storing the result of flatten? For example, you just want to feed the network some images and then get back the results and store them in a file? And don't you want to train the model at all?

Comment: I want to feed the network an image and get an array (one row, n columns) created after I flatten everything. I don't want to train the model.

Comment: Well, I can train the model or use a CNN already trained (VGG, Inception). But after that, I'd like to do what I just said.

Comment: Ok, then you first train the model (otherwise the output of layers may not be useful when the model is not trained) and then define another model or a custom backend function to get the output of some layers **given some input data**. You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53437377/2099607) for more info. Don't forget to look at the link referenced at the end, as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting close. I did what the person in the answer you've sent me said, using keras.models.Model. I created my new model but, when I try to use it to a single image, it complains that the input should have 4 dimensions (Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (197, 180, 3)). Do you know how could I fix that?

Comment: Ok, got it! Had to reshape the image before putting it to the Model. Did 
x = imageio.imread('my_image.png')
x = np.reshape(x, (1, 197, 180, 3))
Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the Keras documentation for pretrained models. See the examples about feature extraction, https://keras.io/applications/#extract-features-with-vgg16

Once you have your model, you just do:

`features = model.predict(x)`